# How is directional derivative at a point on a multi-variable function the projection of the gradient vector at that point?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis

Given a dual variable function 
$$f(x,y)$$
the gradient,$\nabla f$, at a point $(x_1,y_1)$ on the surface defined by this function would give us the vector at that point, pointing in the direction of the greatest change of the function. And given a random vector, $u$ at that same point, the directional derivative of the function along this random vector gives us the slope or the rate of change along the direction pointed by the vector. This directional derivative can also be given as the dot product of (projection of) the gradient vector,$\nabla f$, with this random vector $u$. How is this possible as  another function,
$$g(x,y)$$ 
with the same gradient as that of $f(x,y)$, at $(x_1,y_1)$, but different slope in the direction $u$ is also possible.

Is it because the angle between these two vectors on the different surfaces would be different?

Comment: The theorem is true, when the function is differentiable at the point. This condition imposes a restriction on how all directional derivatives at the point can be related. As you said in general (if differentiability is not given) the gradient, the vector formed by the derivatives in the directions of the axes doesn't need to be related to derivatives in other directions.

Comment: Differentiability at $x_0$ means that there is a vector $G$ such that $\lim_{x\to x_0}\frac{|f(x)-f(x_0)-G\cdot(x-x_0)|}{\|x-x_0\|}=0$ (here $x$ and $x_0$ are elements of $\mathbb{R}^2$). If that $G$ exists it coincides with the gradient. But, as you can see, the limit lets $x$ approach $x_0$ in any way, in particular along any radial direction, while the same $G$ should make the limit zero. Assuming differentiability and restricting the moment of $x$ along the direction of your vector $u$ you get that the limit is saying that $G\cdot u$ satisfies the definition of directional derivative.

Comment: Consider the relationship of $\nabla f$ and the normal of the tangent plane to $z=f(x,y)$ at the point.

Comment: Be very careful: $\nabla f$ is a vector in the plane, and the graph $z=f(x,y)$ is in 3-space. $\nabla f(x_0,y_0)$ gives the direction in the plane in which the function increases most rapidly at $(x_0,y_0)$, and is therefore perpendicular to the level curve of $f(x,y)$ through the point.

Comment: Funny. Wikipedia just [defines gradient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gradient#Definition) as the vector giving the directional derivative by dot product, thus avoiding the issue. In that case, there is no question that if $f$ has a gradient then it gives the directional derivatives by dot product. But then, your $g$ wouldn't have a gradient, also by definition. In both cases you are still correct, that the dot product relation requires more than existence of directional derivatives and a maximum among them.

Comment: @LB_O: That "definition" only works when the function is in fact *differentiable* at the point. You can have a non-differentiable (even discontinuous) function with directional derivatives (and hence a gradient vector, too) at every point. The dot product formula can then fail to hold.

Comment: @TedShifrin Which definition are you talking about? If you define gradient vector as a vector such that its dot product with all directions vectors gives the directional derivative, then differentiability is not required for the existence of such a vector. You can easily have a non-differentiable function in which all directional derivatives are zero, for example. In that case, the property of giving the directional derivatives by dot product holds just by definition.

Comment: @LB_O: But there are plenty of functions with gradient, say, the zero vector and having nonzero directional derivatives in all other directions!

Comment: @TedShifrin I didn't say it was my favorite definition of gradient. The very first comment I posted wasn't using Wikipedia's definition, for example. All I said in the third comment was that Wikipedia's exposition would allow for existence of gradient, would give the dot product property for free, and not necessarily require differentiability. This as a way of showing how exposition is a separate thing from actual content.

Comment: I didn't follow the whole string, sorry. Good reason Wiki shouldn't be considered a reliable textbook :P @LB_O

Comment: @LB_O In your third comment, you said that the function $g$ wouldn't have a gradient .Is this because its directional derivative in some direction, $u$, wouldn't be a projection of the gradient vector and so by definition the function, $g$, is not differentiable at that point?